# AngularDART component

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I made the below simple code while learning AngularDART Component, but nothing is displayed, can anyone help me knowing what mistake I made:

my html main file:

```dart
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <title>AngularDART training</title>
        <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
        <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app>
        <h1 id='text_id'>Welcome</h1>
        <the-component></the-component>
    </body>
    </html>
```

the main.dart file is:

```dart
      import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
      import 'package:angular/application_factory.dart';

      @Component(
          selector: 'the-component',
          templateUrl: 'angularComponent.html',
          cssUrl: 'angularComponent.css',
          publishAs: 'cmp')
      class myComponent {var name = 'Component';}

      main() {
        var module = new Module()
                         ..bind(myComponent);

        applicationFactory().addModule(module).run();
      }
```

the angularComponent.html file is:
       `<p>This is the angular: {{cmp.name}}</p>`

the `<the-component></the-component>` is not working, and not displaying anything!

thanks

Comment: Any error/warning messages when you launch the app?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I got the below error the DART editor.

ShadowRoot.resetStyleInheritance and ShadowRoot.applyAuthorStyles now deprecated in dart:html.
Please remove them from your code.

No getter for 'cmp'.

STACKTRACE:
#0      StaticClosureMap.lookupGetter (package:angular/core/parser/parser_static.dart:15:25)
#1      DynamicParserBackend.newAccessScope (package:angular/core/parser/dynamic_parser.dart:108:38)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer.....After many trials and errors, considering the error msg I get is "  No getter for 'cmp'.    " I entered dummy variable as below, and the component worked perfectly!!     
<the-component anything={{cmp}}></the-component>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all who tried to help, the solution was writing the pubspec.yaml as:

```
dependencies:
angular: '>=0.12.0 <0.13.0'
transformers:
- angular: {html_files: "web/angularComponent.html"}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That helped me a lot! Thanks!
However is there any explanation on what does that sting mean?

Answer (score 3):

Angular transformer picks the components from the `lib` folder. If you place your component's files (.dart, .html, .css) in other folders (i.e. `web`), you need to specify them in the transformers section of pubspec.yaml.

For example,

```
transformers
   - angular:
     -html_files:
        - absolute/path/to/your/html
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Hi @Jose David Aroesi, it gave me this error: Error in pubspec for package "angular_component" loaded from pubspec.yaml:
"transformers.angular" field must be a map, but was "[{html_files: [web/angularComponent.html]}]".

Answer (score 1):

The bug is that your `pubspec.yaml` doesn't list `angularComponent.html` as an asset.

The Angular transformer which creates the `StaticClosureMap` did not parse the template, never saw the `cmp.name` expression and never generated a getter.

We should have given you a better error message.  If you still have the complete project isolated well, please file a bug on [the Github project](http://github.com/angular/angular.dart) and we can make this experience better.

Comment: Thanks @James deBoer, this is something new for me... so, shall I make the pupspec.yaml file as below, or something else...


name: angular_dart_example
version: 0.0.1
dependencies:
  angular:

transformers:
- angular
entry_points: web/angularComponent.html

Comment: I tried adding this line 'entry_points: web/angularComponent.html' but noting changes

Comment: If you could post your sample app somewhere, I can take a look at the configuration.